# Change variable value(C program)

Tags: c

```
int main(void)
{
  int a=5;
  fun();
  printf("%d",a);
  return 0;
}
```

I need to write body of function *fun()* such that printf will print **15**.  I cant change the prototype of *fun()* i.e. it cant be **passed** anything and I can not modify any thing in the `main()` function

Comment: Please tell us what ideas you have as to how it might be done.

Comment: It is a question to say - have you being paying attention in class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warning - horrific hack incoming:

```
void fun()
{
    int b;
    int *a = &b;
    while(*a != 5)
    {
        a++;
    }
    *a = 15;
}
```

This searches the stack for the value we expect for the variable we want to modify, on the assumption that it will have the same alignment as a locally declared int. It also assumes that the variable will in fact be in the stack (it could be optimised away), and that we won't find any other location with the relevant number in. These are, naturally, dangerous assumptions. If the assumptions prove incorrect, bad things will likely happen. I am not responsible for any injury, loss of limb, or death that results in using a hack like this.

Alternatively, and somewhat safer:

```
void fun()
{
    printf("1");
}
```

Comment: alternatively is nice. How does the first hack work?

Comment: Two nice tricks, specially first one. searching for `5` value :-)))

Comment: @Aniket It searches the stack for the value we expect the variable we want to modify, on the assumption that it will have the same alignment as a locally declared int. It also assumes that the variable will in fact be *in* the stack, and that we won't find any other location with the relevant number in. These are, naturally, dangerous assumptions.

Comment: what if `5` is found before finding the real `5` in `a`?

Comment: @Aniket Then something bad will likely happen.

Comment: 1st method is not good. too many restrictions. 2nd method is smart ans +1 for the warning **" I am not responsible for any injury, loss of limb, or death that results in using a hack like this."** :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is just tagged `[c]`. **What you are asking cannot be done using correct, portable C, unless either `a` or `fun()` are defined differently.**

If this question is about stack smashing attacks, it is unanswerable without:

- knowing that this is what the question is about;
- knowing full details of the target hardware architecture and the OS.

Answer (score 1):

---

if you cannot change the prototype of `fun()` then make it a macro ;-)

```
#define fun() (a = 15)

int main(void)
{
  int a=5;
  fun();
  printf("%d",a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are passing an address to the function.

Comment: -1 You know Marcos and functions are two different things.

Comment: @MM. other than a macro not being a function, I said previously turn `fun` into a `macro` for a reason.

Comment: _if you cannot change the prototype of fun() then ..._ *DELETE THE FUNCTION!*

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun();

int main(void)
{
  int a=5;
  fun();
  printf("%d", a); 
  return 0;
}

void fun() {
  int p[1];
  p[11] = 15; 
  printf("%d\n", p[11]);
}
```

Comment: It is modifying a from the stack

Comment: Well, stack, just like another answer